# The pages not loading in ng view by Routers

Tags: angularjs, routes, angularjs-routing

```
    <head>
    <script src=jquery.js></script> 
    <script src=bootstrap.js></script> 

    <script src=angular.js></script> 
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0rc1/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <link rel=stylesheet type="text/css" href=bootstrap.css /> 
    <link rel=stylesheet type=text/css href=mystyle.css /> 

    <style>
        #panel{margin:20px;}
        #addNew{margin:10px;}
        #pagination{text-align:center;}
        span{background:#aaa;width:60px;width:60px;}
    </style> 

</head>

<body ng-app="myApp">

    <div ng-controller=myController> 

         <div id=panel class="panel panel-primary"> 
            <div class="panel-heading">Hero Selection Bar</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <a href="#/one">Page 1</a>
                <a href="#/two">Page 2</a>
                <a href="#/three">Page 3</a>

                <ng-view > </ng-view> 

            </div>
        </div> 
    </div> 


    <script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp',['ngRoute']);

    app.controller('myController', function( $scope, $routeProvider){
        $scope.somedata = "THAT"; 
    });

    app.config([$routeProvider],function($routeProvider){
        $routeProvider
        .when('#/one',  {templateUrl:"templates/one.html"})
        .when('#/two',  {templateUrl:"templates/two.html"})
        .when('#/three',    {templateUrl:"templates/three.html"})
    });  

    </script>
</body>
```

I have kept the files on templates/one.html, templates/two.html, and templates/three.html in 'templates folder' but I am unable to get the pages load in current angularjs page. Can someone help me out in getting the routes load the required pages.

Comment: Remove # from .when('#/') and check if it load

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are couple of things your are doing wrong:-

1)# in when not required it should be like `.when('/one',  {templateUrl:"templates/one.html"})` etc.

2)Array notation must be end at the end `['$routeProvider']` not correct

It should be like :-

```
app.config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider){
        $routeProvider
        .when('/one',  {templateUrl:"one.html"})
        .when('/two',  {templateUrl:"two.html"})
        .when('/three',    {templateUrl:"three.html"}).otherwise({redirectTo:'/one'})
    }]);
```

3)`$routeProvider` not required in controller use `$route`.

4) I guess use otherwise it also required (It is optional).

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/TrV9m0c6zCTT05ovdV6e?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

You added `[$routeProvider]` which has `]` which should be closing bracket of dependency.

**Config**

```
  app.config([$routeProvider,function($routeProvider){
        $routeProvider
        .when('/one',  {templateUrl:"templates/one.html"})
        .when('/two',  {templateUrl:"templates/two.html"})
        .when('/three',    {templateUrl:"templates/three.html"})
    }]);
```

Inside controller you can not inject `$routeProvider` dependency it should `$route`

Comment: and $routeprovider in controller not valid.

Comment: @squiroid yes it should be $route

Comment: @squiroid you are champ dude :p